# How to select a identical element nested element with Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to automate a test step with Selenium. The problem is that I have an element I can't reach by name or id. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
<div class="well">
<label class="question">
    Are you already member?
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input id="IsClient" name="IsClient" onchange="toggle(this)" type="radio" value="true">  Yes, I want to register.
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input id="IsClient" name="IsClient" onchange="toggle(this)" type="radio" value="false"> No, I'm already registered. 
</label>
..
```

Comment: What is the element and where it is located in html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be simply locate by using their `value` attribute with `cssSelector` as below :-

- To select `Yes, I want to register` radio :-

  ```
  input#IsClient[value='true']
  ```
- To select `No, I'm already registred` radio

  ```
  input#IsClient[value='false']
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following css selectors:

```
input#IsClient[value='false']
label.radio-inline:nth-of-type(2) .input#IsClient
```

Or xpath:

```
//input[@id='IsClient'][contains(text(), 'No')]
```